# Incorrect values displayed on LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

I have created a simple LWC to display a list of account records in a box on clicking of a button but the records displayed on the grid are getting repeated.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<AccountDetailsWrapper> getAccountDetails(){
    try {
            List<AccountDetailsWrapper> wrapperList = new List<AccountDetailsWrapper>();
            AccountDetailsWrapper wrapperObj = new AccountDetailsWrapper();
            String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';
            for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Type, Website FROM Account]){
                wrapperObj.accountId = baseUrl + acc.Id;
                wrapperObj.accountName = acc.Name;
                wrapperObj.accountPhone = acc.Phone;
                wrapperObj.accountType = acc.Type;
                wrapperObj.accountWebsite = acc.Website;
                wrapperList.add(wrapperObj);
            }
            return wrapperList;
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}  
public class AccountDetailsWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountId{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountName{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountPhone{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountType{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountWebsite{get; set;}
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Account Grid">
    <lightning-button class="slds-p-around_medium" label="Show accounts in grid" onclick={showAccounts}
        variant="brand"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-layout class="slds-p-around_medium" multiple-rows>
        <template if:true={hasData}>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                <lightning-layout-item class="slds-m-around_large" key={account.accountId} size="2">
                    <div class="slds-box slds-align_absolute-center">
                        <!-- <lightning-formatted-text value={account.Name}></lightning-formatted-text> -->
                        <lightning-formatted-url label={account.accountName} value={account.accountId}
                            target="_blank"></lightning-formatted-url>
                    </div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccountDetails';

export default class AccountGrid extends LightningElement {
@track accounts;
error;
hasData = false;

// @wire(getAccounts)
// getAllAccounts({data, error}){
//     if(data){    
//     this.hasData = data.length > 0 ? true : false;
//     this.accounts = data;
//     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.accounts))
//     this.error = undefined;
//     }
//     else{
//         this.error = error;
//         this.data = undefined;
//     }
// }

    
showAccounts(){
    getAccounts()
    .then(result => {
        this.accounts = result;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.accounts));
        this.hasData = result.length > 0 ? true : false;
    }).catch(error => {
        this.error = error.body.message;
    })}

}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You have one mistake in the apex controller. You need to write `AccountDetailsWrapper wrapperObj = new AccountDetailsWrapper();` inside the loop, not the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you have written `AccountDetailsWrapper wrapperObj = new AccountDetailsWrapper();` in wrong place.

You need to initailize `AccountDetailsWrapper` within each loop.

```
    AccountDetailsWrapper wrapperObj = new AccountDetailsWrapper();
    wrapperObj.accountId = baseUrl + acc.Id;
    wrapperObj.accountName = acc.Name;
    wrapperObj.accountPhone = acc.Phone;
    wrapperObj.accountType = acc.Type;
    wrapperObj.accountWebsite = acc.Website;
    wrapperList.add(wrapperObj);
```

So that it creates new instance of wrapper and add it to the list.

In your case as the initialization is outside loop, thus every time you do `wrapperList.add(wrapperObj);,` you're adding a reference to the same object. Any change made to wrapperObj in a later iteration will reflect in all the objects already in the list, making them appear the same.

Comment: Thanks Nagendra!